# How to get label text from child of class inside of each loop? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, foreach, label, children

so I'm currently stuck on trying to get the label text of a couple of input fields

[image]

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/fJGie

^ in the codepen above I have created 2 phone input fields. However haven't been able to get the label text of each one. Originally I had the `added_phone` class on the input, but since moved that to the parent `li`.

I tried `$(this.children)` no error, but no output, tried var tag = `$(this).children.label.text()` but got an error

[image]

```
var elems = $('.added_phone');

elems.each( function(i) {
  console.log(i);

  var tag = $(this.children.label).text();
  var value = $(this).val();

  console.log('tag = '+tag);
  console.log('value = '+value);
});
```

Do you see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: that's a very odd error to get... are you sure `$ === jQuery`?

Comment: yes, I'm using the jQuery lib in codepen, also in my project.

Comment: if you use your debugger, you'll see the error happens here: `var tag = $(this).children.label.text();` that's obviously wrong. $.fn.children is a function, and does not have a property, and undefined doesn't have a text property.

Comment: So, the code in your question doesn't match the codepen, and both of them are wrong.

Comment: in the codepen code, you have `$(this).children.label.text()`, `children` is a function, `label` is undefined, and `text` throws an error because `undefined` can't have properties, hence the error you are getting. The error message you are getting says `label` is undefined.

Comment: What you probably meant was `$(this).children("label").text()`

Comment: WOOT I just figured it out `var tag = $(this).children("label").text();` http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/fJGie hehe thanks :) you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).children.label.text()
```

is invalid syntax for jQuery, you probably meant this:

```
$(this).children("label").text()
```